# GetTwinAsync() are not supported in IoT edge Simulator v0.14.10

Tags: .net-core, azure-iot-edge

GetTwinAsync() returns always Twin object with empty properties, all properties of my IoT edge module are null when I run my IoT edge device in Simulator, in my Linux server works everything fine. I should wait also about 20 seconds to get a response from GetTwinAync().

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we look at it, this problem is expected. If you read this [Understand and use module twins in IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins) document, then you will see that from module app, only has permission to read desired properties and read/write reported properties. If you check this image below you will understand better.

[image: Module-twin]

The lifecycle of a module twin is linked to the corresponding module identity. Modules twins are implicitly created and deleted when a module identity is created or deleted in IoT Hub.

To access all module properties, you can do it from solution back end and require the ServiceConnect permission. You will need Microsoft.Azure.Devices V1.16.0-preview-001 or later. The following is a console app code snippet.

```cs
...
RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString); 
Module module; 
try 
{ 
module = await registryManager.AddModuleAsync(new Module(deviceID, moduleID)); 
} 
catch (ModuleAlreadyExistsException)
{ 
module = await registryManager.GetModuleAsync(deviceID, moduleID); 
}
...
```

For more detailed explanation and example check this [Get started with IoT Hub module identity and module twin (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-module-twin-getstarted). If your issue still persist then you can open an issue on [azure-iot-sdk-csharp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp) repository.